# Strip prefix to remove the environment passed in URL

Tags: netflix-zuul

My frontend application attaches an environment attribute as a prefix in the URI -- I am having difficulty getting Zuul to strip this prefix.

For example, the frontend application is making a request to Zuul proxy locally http://localhost:9080/local/domains/metrs/subdomains/medicare/base-templates/. Zuul needs to strip out the environment "local" as seen in the URL and then forward to the web service located (with the environment "local" stripped) at http://localhost:9090/icews/admin/domains/metrs/subdomains/medicare/base-templates/

Unfortunately, I get a 404 error because the prefix "local" is not being stripped -- when reading the logs on the server hosting the web service, I still see the environment "local" forwarded in the call.

Here is my Zuul configuration:

```
ice.ws.local.url=http://localhost:9090/icews/admin
ice.ws.dev.url=http://developmentserver/icews/admin

zuul.routes.base-templates.path=/local/**/base-templates/**
zuul.routes.base-templates.url=${ice.ws.local.url}
zuul.routes.base-templates.strip-prefix=true

zuul.routes.base-templates.path=/dev/**/base-templates/**
zuul.routes.base-templates.url=${ice.ws.dev.url}
zuul.routes.base-templates.strip-prefix=true
```

***UPDATE***
I went ahead and used the approach as outlined here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1893 and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2408

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the strip-prefix in the application.properties but instead followed the approach outlined here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1893

Specifically for my case where I have a frontend that needs to route on different environments (each being a different microservice), I have another Zuul filter that runs in order 6 (PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER + 1):

```
@Component
public class PostDecorFilter extends ZuulFilter {

@Value("${zuul.PostSendResponseCustomFilter.post.disable:false}")
private boolean isDisableFilter;

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    // run this filter after zuul..PreDecorationFilter
    return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER + 1;
}

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return PRE_TYPE;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return !isDisableFilter;
}

/**
 * Add custom response processing here
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Object run() {

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    // environment is added by frontend Angular app, e.g. dev, dev-t, qa, qa-t
    String environment = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURI().split("/")[1];

    if ( "dev".equals(environment) || "dev-t".equals(environment) || "qa".equals(environment) || "qa-t".equals(environment) ) {

        // e.g. /dev/some/resource/
        String requestUriWithEnvironment = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURI();

        // e.g. /some/resource/
        String requestUriWithoutEnvironment =
                requestUriWithEnvironment.substring(environment.length() + 1);

        context.put(REQUEST_URI_KEY, requestUriWithoutEnvironment);

    }

    return null;

}
```

I also had to use a CustomRouteLocator as outlined here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2408

The reason is that the paths in application.properties are

```
ice.ws.local.url=http://localhost:9090/icews/admin
ice.ws.dev.url=http://developmentserver/icews/admin

zuul.routes.base-templates.path=/local/**/base-templates/**
zuul.routes.base-templates.url=${ice.ws.local.url}

zuul.routes.base-templates.path=/dev/**/base-templates/**
zuul.routes.base-templates.url=${ice.ws.dev.url}
```

Essentially, I was experiencing the same behavior as outlined here: "it seems that SimpleRouteLocator iterates over all routes, not in the order they're in config file and just pick the first match" https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2408